# Differentiate devices in MPLAB X IDE

Tags: ide, microchip, mplab

I have a code that will be used to program a board (using a Pickit3 controller)that contains 2 devices. Within the code contains the initialization for both of these devices in 2 separate functions. How do I use device indices to determine which function to execute? Each of these functions writes to registers that these devices seem to share...

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided models so I cannot link to specific datasheets but most devices have a read only DeviceID register that you could read. Although I suspect you wont be able to compile your app in a way that will work for both devices as although they share register names (ex. in C) the memory mapping often changes slightly from one device to the next and the compiled applications relie on memory mapping not register names. Your best bet is probably to setup two project configurations and use conditional compilation to compile ether one config or the other.

Comment: The two devices are the BCM89810 and BCM89811. What do you mean by setting up two project configurations? Two separate projects altogether?

Comment: Not two different projects but one project with two different build configurations, one that would include the file containing the configuration for one processor and the other that would include a different file with the configuration for the other processor. For as to how to manage this,... you tagged your post with MPLAB (a microchip IDE) but you specified broadcom devices and I've never worked with a broadcom IDE.

Comment: Well I looked a little more into these devices and it seems I misunderstood the original question. If I understand correctly you have a single PIC microchip device that can connect to an external device that will be ether BCM89810 or a BCM89811?